# Python Pandas: add column in a dataframe based on a matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, merge

I have two dataframes. One has daily data and the other one has hourly data. Both the dataframes cover the exact time period (about 2 years)

Dataframe 1 looks like this:

```
0   2017-01-01  963.658020  998.325012  0.035974    False   False
1   2017-01-02  998.617004  1021.750000     0.023165    False   False
2   2017-01-03  1021.599976     1043.839966     0.021770    False   False
3   2017-01-04  1044.400024     1154.729980     0.105640    True    False
4   2017-01-05  1156.729980     1013.380005     -0.123927   False   True
```

Dataframe 2 looks like this:

```
0   2017-01-01  00:00:00    974.55  972.00  -0.002617
1   2017-01-01  01:00:00    972.00  970.55  -0.001492
2   2017-01-01  02:00:00    970.55  969.89  -0.000680
3   2017-01-01  03:00:00    969.89  967.80  -0.002155
4   2017-01-01  04:00:00    967.80  967.80  0.000000
```

I want to add the last two Boolean columns to my hourly dataframe. If a given day in dataframe 1 has a boolean value false, I want that value to be added to all the rows in dataframe 2 which correspond to that date.
I don't know if merge will work here because dataframe 2 doesn't have any unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your first column of two dataframes is `date` and `datetime`. Boolean columns in `df1` is `boolean1` and `boolean2`.

First convert your first column to datetime type

```py
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime'])
```

Then create `df2` boolean column based on `date` column of `df1`

```
df2['boolean1'] = df2['datetime'].dt.date.map(df1.set_index('date')['boolean1'])
df2['boolean2'] = df2['datetime'].dt.date.map(df1.set_index('date')['boolean2'])
```

At last, filter out rows in `df2` where two boolean columns are all True

```py
m = df2[['boolean1', 'boolean2']].all(axis=1)
df2 = df2[~m]
```